# Как сдвинуть все id в базе данных, если удаляется один

Tags: python, sqlite3

Я делаю авторынок для своего бота, у реализовал покупку, после покупки определеннного авто, оно удалится из базы. Так вот проблема: когда оно удаляется, другие иды не смещются за ним и получается пробел который вызывает ошибку. Как после удаления смещать `id`?

Comment: Обычно id придумывают специально для того, чтобы они были постоянные и никогда не менялись, так что вы хотите странного. Ну а как смещать — просто выполнить UPDATE-запрос, который вычтет 1 откуда нужно, наверное?

Comment: тут ид используется как id авто на рынке, поэтому при покупке авто, логично его удалить с рынка

Comment: Правильней будет исправить код, который зависит от того, что id должны быть по порядку и без пробелов

Comment: Удалить id — логично, а вот ставить на место удалённого id какое-то другое авто — совсем не логично

Comment: Вот захотят пользователи потом разобрать какой-то инцидент - что-то пошло не так. А у вас получается было несколько разных авто с одним `id` в базе в разное время. Зачем усложнять себе жизнь? `id` должен быть уникальным, не нужно их экономить.

Answer (score 0):

смог решить вопрос данным куском кода:

```py
try:
    sql.execute(f"UPDATE carmarket SET id=id-1 WHERE id > {id}")
    db.commit()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Оно конечно да, но лучше так не делать, почитайте комментарии.

Comment: Это решение не будет работать в сценарии, когда приходят одновременно два запроса: первый удаляет автомобиль, а второй добавляет. В этом случае запрос на добавление сгенерирует новый id для автомобиля, но еще не зафиксирует транзакцию, т.е. не сделает commit. Запрос на удаление, еще не будет видеть эту новую запись с новым id автомобиля и соответственно `UPDATE`, который сдвигает `id` не будет модифицировать этот новый id, так что "дырка" все равно останется.

Comment: Ну и другие даже более серьезные проблемы возможны. Показали пользователю автомобиль на странице с `id=10`, после этого кто-то другой удалил автомобиль с `id=3`, теперь первый пользователь пробует что-то делать с автомобилем `id=10`, а это уже совсем другой автомобиль. Это означает, что все приложение должно быть написано так (и об этом нужно постоянно не забывать), что id автомобиля может измениться в любой момент. Это, конечно, можно учесть. Но это очень ненадежно и трудоемко, так что не имеет смысла.